# How do you use a category to add a method to an Apple class?

Tags: cocoa, xcode6, categories

I have an app that uses Core Data, and everything is working well.  Now, as an exercise, I am trying to add a method to one of Apple's classes using a category:

```
//
//  NSManagedObjectContext+Report.h
//  BookshelfCoreData
//


//#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSManagedObjectContext(Report)

-(void)MY_report;

@end
```

...

```
//
//  NSManagedObjectContext+Report.m
//  BookshelfCoreData
//


#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "NSManagedObjectContext+Report.h"

@implementation NSManagedObjectContext(Report)

-(void)MY_report {
    NSLog(@"%@", [self description]);
}

@end
```

And I attempt to use the new method here:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NSManagedObjectContext+Report.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

-(IBAction)createReport:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"createReport...");

    NSSet* registeredObjs = [[self managedObjectContext] registeredObjects];

    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[registeredObjs count]);

    for(NSManagedObjectContext* element in registeredObjs) {
        NSLog(@"In for loop..");

        if ( [element respondsToSelector:@selector(MY_report)] ) {
            NSLog(@"In if statement...");
            [element MY_report];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

I have a button in my window which triggers the `createReport:` action.  Here's the `NSLog()` output:

```
2015-06-04 18:06:03.811 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] createReport...
2015-06-04 18:06:03.811 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] 9
2015-06-04 18:06:03.811 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] In for loop..
2015-06-04 18:06:03.811 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] In for loop..
2015-06-04 18:06:03.812 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] In for loop..
2015-06-04 18:06:03.812 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] In for loop..
2015-06-04 18:06:03.812 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] In for loop..
2015-06-04 18:06:03.812 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] In for loop..
2015-06-04 18:06:03.812 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] In for loop..
2015-06-04 18:06:03.812 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] In for loop..
2015-06-04 18:06:03.813 BookshelfCoreData[811:16689] In for loop..
```

So, it's apparent that an NSManagedObjectContext does not respond to the selector `MY_report`.  What am I doing wrong?

**As pointed out by @Josh Caswell**: I was modifying the wrong Apple class with my category.  Instead, I needed to modify the `NSManagedObject` class.  This works:

```
//
//  NSManagedObject+Report.h
//  BookshelfCoreData
//

//#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSManagedObject(Report)

-(void) MY_report;

@end
```

...

```
//
//  NSManagedObject+Report.m
//  BookshelfCoreData
//

#import "NSManagedObject+Report.h"

@implementation NSManagedObject(Report)

-(void) MY_report {
    NSLog(@"%@", [self description]);
}

@end
```

...

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  BookshelfCoreData
//


#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NSManagedObject+Report.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

-(IBAction)createReport:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"createReport...");

    NSSet* registeredObjs = [[self managedObjectContext] registeredObjects];

    for(NSManagedObject* element in registeredObjs) {
        if ( [element respondsToSelector:@selector(MY_report)] ) {
            [element MY_report];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

...

```
--output:--
2015-06-04 18:48:21.702 BookshelfCoreData[1244:25831] createReport...
2015-06-04 18:48:21.702 BookshelfCoreData[1244:25831] <NSManagedObject: 0x6080000ad200> (entity: Chapter; id: 0x60800003af00 <x-coredata://723DF43C-82DB-423C-AAD9-E41BE5C9900A/Chapter/p112> ; data: {
    book = "0x60800003afc0 <x-coredata://723DF43C-82DB-423C-AAD9-E41BE5C9900A/PragBook/p114>";
    chapterNumber = 1;
    title = Chap1;
})
2015-06-04 18:48:21.703 BookshelfCoreData[1244:25831] <NSManagedObject: 0x6080000aff60> (entity: PragBook; id: 0x60800003ada0 <x-coredata://723DF43C-82DB-423C-AAD9-E41BE5C9900A/PragBook/p109> ; data: {
    authors = "<relationship fault: 0x60000002abc0 'authors'>";
    chapters = "<relationship fault: 0x60000002b120 'chapters'>";
    title = aaa;
})

...
...
...
```

Comment: `element` must not be an `NSManagedObjectContext`

Comment: @JoshCaswell, Ah hah.  element is an NSManagedObject.  How about posting your comment as an answer?